# reverse returning an empty string in get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use reverse for get_absolute_url in one of my models. However, it's returning blank string.

url.py

```
url(
    regex=r'^$',
    view=SocietyView.as_view(),
    name='society',
),
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<tagname>[\w ]+)/?$',
    view=SocietyView.as_view(),
    name='society_with_tag',
),
```

model.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, related_name='tags', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("society_with_tag", kwargs={"tagname": self.name})
```

template.html

```
<a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">
    {{ tag.name }}
</a>
```

result.html

```
<a href="">
    tag
</a>
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Django's `reverse()` function, but shouldn't the `kwarg` key in `get_absolute_url()` be `"tag.name"`, not `"tagname"`?

Comment: The kwargs are for url.py, which has <tagname> as a parameter name in it. Therefore, "tagname" is correct. I think...

Comment: Ah. I see, as I said, I'm unfamiliar with the Django framework.

Comment: just try `reverse('society_with_tag', args=[self.name, ])`

Comment: are you using 1.5 django? if so you might have to provide the app name

Comment: no luck with `reverse('society_with_tag', args=[self.name, ])` I'm using 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why but removing ',' in the end solved this problem.

Both catherine and caio gave me great answers but since I am not using 1.5, that wasn't it.

I changed

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("society_with_tag", args=[self.name,])
```

into

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("society_with_tag", args=[self.name])
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to provide the `app_name`

```
@property
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("app_name:society_with_tag", args=[self.name])
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you are validating the tag name so it will always match your regex `[\w ]+`

Otherwise you can use a more generalist regex `[^/]+` that will match anything until the next `/`

For example, in your urls.py, use:

```
url(r'^(?P<tagname>[^/]+)/$', SocietyView.as_view(),
    name='society_with_tag'),
```

*Note that you only need "/?" if you changed the default value of* [APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) *to False*

And in your models.py:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('society_with_tag', [self.name])
```

Remember that if you are using [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) you will need to add the prefix to the view name:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('app_name:society_with_tag', [self.name])
```